# random split vs temporal/time based split

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, train-test-split

Some background: I want to train a regression model to predict **future prices** for used cars. I have about 85,000 observations collected from November 2022 to June 2023 and have around 80 different columns/features including the timestamp when the car was listed and the price it was sold at.

Based on this background of the problem, do you suggest to go for a random split for example using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` or to go for a temporal/time based split for example where observations till May 2023 are in the train set and observations in June 2023 are in the test set.

I went through the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565740/random-split-vs-time-based-split-of-train-and-test-data) but it seems it's difficult to model time in this case because I barely have data for a complete year. Assuming that I had data for 2+ complete years I believe a random split would have worked as I could have used time as a feature but since I barely have data for about 8 months I believe a temporal split would be more appropriate.

Let me know which one - random split or temporal split would you suggest for this use case.